# Failed to resolve dependency Ext.grid.Panel on ExtJS 6.0

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs6

I am having the following error when trying to extend 'Ext.grid.Panel' which is shown in the example on Sencha official documentation. I used both classic, modern, universal framework and still it is not working.

```
Failed to resolve dependency Ext.grid.Panel for file Xmlgrid.view.main.Main
    [ERR] 
    [ERR] BUILD FAILED
    [ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.grid.Panel
    [ERR]   at o
    [ERR] rg.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    [ERR] 
    [ERR] Total time: 65 minutes 56 seconds
    [ERR] Error during rebuild : The following error occurred while executing this line:
    C:\Users\nandeesh\workspace\Xmlgrid\.sencha\app\watch-impl.xml:4: The following error occurred while executing this line:
    C:\Users\nandeesh\workspace\Xmlgrid\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:380: The following error occurred while executing this line:
    C:\Users\nandeesh\workspace\Xmlgrid\.sencha\app\init-impl.xml:403: com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.grid.Panel
    [INF] Refresh complete in 0 sec. at 10:59:30 AM
```

Comment: Did you require the grid class?

Comment: @incutonez The class ext.grid.Panel shows up in the api documentation but why can't i extend it in my project.

Comment: You can't take their examples as the source of truth, as they're most likely including every class by default.  If you're building using Sencha Cmd, you might have to include the class itself in the [`requires`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-requires) block.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 3):

I also have to fix this error with a 6.5.0 Sencha Cmd version and a 6.2.0 Ext JS version.
I answer certainly a bit late for you @random aspirer but for those who search actually here it is.
 The issue comes from your toolkit config defined in your app.json so : 
- If you have this :

```
"toolkit" : "modern",
```

replace it by

```
"toolkit" : "classic",
```

Solution reference : https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?303033-Unknown-definition-for-dependency

Comment: Edited ! Thanks for the advice.